# Prove that if $(ab)^2 = e$, then $(ba)^2 = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group, and let $a,b \in G$ be such that

$$(ab)^2 = e.$$

Prove that $(ba)^2 = e$.

Comment: Did you have any thoughts of your own on the matter?

Comment: (ab)^-1=b^-1 a^-1=ab . b(b^-1 a^-1) a = b(ab)a=e

Answer (score 24):

Hint:

If $(ab)^{2} = abab = e$, right multiply both sides by $a$. Then we have $a(baba) = a$. Now use the uniqueness of the identity.

Answer (score 10):

*Hint:* Consider $a^{-1}ea$ and see what gives.

Answer (score 7):

$(ab)^n=e$, then $(ba)^n=e$. Here are two proofs:

1. In fact, $(ab)^n=e$, so
   $$b(ab)^n=b$$
   associative law
   $$(ba)^nb=b$$
   we get that $(ba)^n=e$.
2. $ab$ and  $ba$  conjugacy elements: $ab=a(ba)a^{-1}$

Answer (score 6):

Given: $(ab)^2 = e$.

Knowing that $$(ab)^{2} = abab = e$$ then using right multiplication by $a$, we have $$(abab)a = ea = a \iff a(baba) = a$$

But the identity $e$ in any group is unique. Hence,  $$\;a(baba) = {\bf a}(ba)^2 = {\bf a} \implies (ba)^2 = e$$

That is, we have both $(ab)^2 = (ba)^2 = e$.

Answer (score 6):

$$abab = e$$
$$a^{-1}abab = a^{-1}$$
$$bab= a^{-1}$$
$$baba = a^{-1}a$$
$$baba = e$$

Answer (score 3):

Useful fact to prove: for all $a,b\in G$ [ $(bab^{-1})^n=ba^nb^{-1}$]